# XMLHttpRequest is not defined in Cloud9 IDE?

Tags: xmlhttprequest, cloud9-ide

I defined a `XMLHttpRequest` in the Cloud9 IDE like this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

But it prompted an error, saying `ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined`.

Is `XMLHttpRequest` defined in Cloud9 IDE?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running your javascript file via the 'Debug' button then it will be executed in [node.js](http://nodejs.org/), which doesn't contain `XMLHttpRequest` (because it's a browser feature).

If the file you're developing is a client side file, rather open the HTML page that references the js file via the 'Preview' button.

Otherwise, you can use [node-XMLHttpRequest](https://github.com/driverdan/node-XMLHttpRequest), that mimics the browser behavior, or [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request), which is the de-factor standard of doing requests to other services for nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked awhile ago but in case someelse encounters the same issue here is how to fix it.

You need to define the XMLHttpRequest in a function first before you try to create an object with it.

Here is an Example:

```
//Define your method reference 
function createXMLHttpRequest() 
   {
    try 
    { 
      return new XMLHttpRequest();
       } catch(e) {}
    try 
    { 
   return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); 
   } catch (e) {}
    alert("Sorry, the XMLHttpRequest is not supported");
    return null;
    }
```

//Now you can start creating an object with the defined createXMLHttpRequest()

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

function oHttp_readyStateChange() 
{
if (oHttp.readyState == 4) 
{
if (oHttp.status == 200) 
{
  alert(oHttp.responseText); 
}
else {
  alert("The server returned a status code of " + oHttp.status);
}
}
}
oHttp.open("GET", "http://myWebsite/Myfile.sql", true);

oHttp.onreadystatechange = oHttp_readyStateChange;

oHttp.send(null);
```